# Jquery dialog icons dissapear when reopen the dialog with div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using dialog with div in the next way:

```
$('#check123').dialog(dialogOptions).dialogExtend(dialogExtendOptions);
```

`#check123` - It's `div` located in the same HTML.

After open it, close and reopen, dialog reopen without minimized and maximized icons.

I tried to change the close method to remove or destroy and it's the same.

```
"close" : function(){ $(this).remove(); }
"close" : function(){ $(this).dialog("destroy");  }
```

The `div` inside is ok, the only problem is missing icons for minimized and maximized after reopen.

thanks

Comment: please create a demo

Comment: can you show the full html with this?

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56593852/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have just come across this bug too. Destroying the dialog does not automatically destroy the dialogExtend state.

Change your close event to destroy the dialogExtend, then destroy the dialog:

```
close: function(event) {
   $(this).dialogExtend("destroy").dialog("destroy");
}
```

This will leave the contents of your #check123 div in place, and destroy and the dialog completely, so it can be re-opened with your specified dialogExtendOptions.